# Parsing HTML source code to get url's of images without errors. (Python preferred)

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I made a wordpress plugin which sends the blogposts as post data so that I can save the webpage. I get the data from the blog using the following query:

```
select * from $wpdb->posts
```

The above line is not important, but just mentioned it to tell you how I am getting the blog data.

The data contains HTML markup. I need to parse the HTML to get the URLs of images . Once I get the URL, I know how to download the images from the URL. I want to know a good way of parsing HTML markup to get the URLs of images without any error.

python is the preferred language.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several python modules that will do this for you:

- BeautifulSoup
- lxml.html
- html5lib

For example,

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = """
  <html><body>
    <h1>My html!</h1>
    <img src="yourimage1.jpg" />
    <img src="yourimage1.jpg" />
  </body></html>
"""

bs = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
urls = [img["src"] for img in bs.findAll("img")]
```

results in `urls == ['yourimage1.jpg', 'yourimage2.jpg']`

Comment: great answer, thanks a lot for the answer . I parsed manually which worked on some and didnt work on some others, so posted question here, and luckily got answer from u . Thanks a lot !